# How do I handle "User Data Collection Acknowledgement" in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics as an "I acknowledge" button under Admin/Property/Data Settings/Data Collection.

The text under it reads: "I acknowledge that I have the necessary privacy disclosures and rights from my end users for the collection and processing of their data, including the association of such data with the visitation information Google Analytics collects from my site and/or app property."

I can't find any explanation of what the necessary privacy disclosures are or what rights I need to get from end users.

What are the disclosures? What are the rights?

Any mention of the button outside of Google only says to simply click it.

Do I need to show users a website popup that they have to agree to?
Do I need put a tiny notice at the bottom of the website?
Do I need to bury legalese deeply inside a terms of use page that nobody reads?
Is this a dirty little secret where Google really needed permission, but they trust that site owners will simply click the button and take culpability for not actually asking the end users?